# VB.NET Importing Classes

Tags: vb.net

**Edit:** This was accidentally posted twice. Original: [VB.NET Importing Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243900/vb-net-importing-classes)

I've seen some code where a *Class* is imported, instead of a namespace, making all the static members/methods of that class available.  Is this a feature of VB?  Or do other languages do this as well?

TestClass.vb

```
public class TestClass
    public shared function Somefunc() as Boolean
        return true
    end function
end class
```

MainClass.vb

```
imports TestClass

public class MainClass
    public sub Main()
        Somefunc()
    end sub
end class
```

These files are in the App_Code directory.  Just curious, because I've never thought of doing this before, nor have I read about it anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET Importing Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243900/vb-net-importing-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Imports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x(VS.80).aspx) only creates a reference to the class, it does not create an instance of it to use.

The reason you see the function in your new class is that it's a [shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x(VS.80).aspx) function, which doesn't need the parent to have a created instance to use.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

By using the "HideModuleNameAttribute" you can call methods without identifying thier parent.

Example:

```
Public Class TestClassCaller
    Public Sub New()
        SomeMethod()
    End Sub

End Class

<HideModuleName()> _
    Public Module TestClass
    Public Sub SomeMethod()

    End Sub
End Module
```